# Journal not displayed in mn2e bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

`@article` entries in my `.bib` file are not being displayed properly in the `.pdf` generated. The 'Journal' is not displayed. I am using `mn2e` bibliography style in
`\documentclass[useAMS,usenatbib]{mn2e}`. The class file can be found at https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mnras/.

```
@ARTICLE{Rogers2009,
   author = {{Rogers}, J.~C. and {Apai}, D. and {L{\'o}pez-Morales}, M. and 
    {Sing}, D.~K. and {Burrows}, A.},
    title = "{Ks-Band Detection of Thermal Emission and Color Constraints to CoRoT-1b: A Low-Albedo Planet with Inefficient Atmospheric Energy Redistribution and a Temperature Inversion}",
  journal = {\apj},
archivePrefix = "arXiv",
   eprint = {0910.1257},
 primaryClass = "astro-ph.EP",
 keywords = {binaries: eclipsing, planetary systems, stars: individual: CoRoT-1, techniques: photometric},
     year = 2009,
    month = dec,
   volume = 707,
      eid = {1707},
    pages = {1707-1716},
      doi = {10.1088/0004-637X/707/2/1707},
   adsurl = {http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2009ApJ...707.1707R},
  adsnote = {Provided by the SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System}
}
```

Rogers J., L ́opez-Morales M., Apai D., Adams E., 2013, ,
767, 64

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the class you are using: it's not on CTAN.

Comment: You might also like to provide a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/), so we can see what your code looks like. Also, are you sure you use `biblatex` as indicated with the tags? Your call to `mn2e` contains `usenatbib`, which - in a way - suggests you use `natbib`.

Comment: @JosephWright, I have provided a link to the class file in the description of the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @moewe, I provided a MWE below. Let me know if I need to clarify anything. Thanks!!

Comment: Well, you use `\apj`/`\mnras` in the `journal` field these commands are not defined anywhere in your document, so either write out the journal name or load a file that defines these abbreviation, e.g. [aas_macros.sty](http://doc.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs_doc/aas_macros.sty).

Comment: To confirm the impression conveyed by @moewe, the `journal` field probably isn't displayed because the macro `\apj` isn't defined. If I construct a MWE based on your code snippet and replace `journal = {\apj},` with, say, `journal = {The Circular File},` the journal name shows up correctly. What error messages are in the `.blg` file -- maybe something about `\apj` not being defined?